# Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Shorthand property assignments are valid only in destructuring patterns

Tags: vuex

I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Shorthand property assignments are valid only in destructuring patterns (74:14)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|         dispatch('ADD_CHILDREN_TO_NODE', {
>           doc = doc,
|         })
|         .finally(() => {
    at eval (document-flow.module.js:1)
    at Object../src/main/code/customers-self-data/vuex/modules/document-flow.module.js (_bundle.js?97212a2ac8be2d4b571f:8449)
    at __webpack_require__ (_bundle.js?97212a2ac8be2d4b571f:20)
    at eval (store.js:8)
    at Module../src/main/code/customers-self-data/vuex/store.js (_bundle.js?97212a2ac8be2d4b571f:8473)
    at __webpack_require__ (_bundle.js?97212a2ac8be2d4b571f:20)
    at eval (index.js:3)
    at Module../src/main/code/customers-self-data/index.js (_bundle.js?97212a2ac8be2d4b571f:8378)
    at __webpack_require__ (_bundle.js?97212a2ac8be2d4b571f:20)
    at eval (index.js:1)
```

This is my module:

```
import * as a from "../types/actions.types";
import * as g from "../types/getters.types";
import * as m from "../types/mutations.types";
import {
  some imports
} from "@pn-js/core";

const documentFlow = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    documentFlowTree: null,
    documentId: null,
    childrens: null,
  },
  getters: {
    [g.GET_DOCUMENT_FLOW_TREE](state) {
      return state.documentFlowTree;
    },
    [g.GET_DOCUMENT_ID](state) {
      return state.documentId;
    },
    [g.GET_CHILDRENS](state) {
      return state.childrens;
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    [m.SET_DOCUMENT_FLOW_TREE](state, payload) {
      state.documentFlowTree = payload;
    },
    [m.SET_DOCUMENT_ID](state, payload) {
      state.documentId = payload.id;
    },
    [m.SET_CHILDRENS](state, payload) {
      state.childrens = payload.childrens;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    [a.LOAD_DOCUMENT_FLOW_TREE]({ dispatch,commit, state }) {
      var _documentTypeNamesMap = {
        ORDER: order,
            DELIVERY: delivery,
            INVOICE: invoice,
      };

      let params = new ParamsBuilder(url)
        .param(ParamsBuilder.UrlReplacements.ID, state.documentId)
        .build();
      let res = [];
      return Http.get({ params }).then((response) => {
        
        //Compongo il nodo root
        let firstNodeText =
          _documentTypeNamesMap.ORDER + ":\t" + state.documentId;
        
        let doc = [];
        if (response.result) {
          Object.keys(response.result).forEach((key) => {
            doc.push(response.result[key].sequentDocuments.filter((d) => {
              return d.docType.category === "DELIVERY";
            }));
          });
        }

        dispatch('ADD_CHILDREN_TO_NODE', { ====> This generates the error
          doc = doc,
        })
        .finally(() => {
          if (response.result) {
            res.push({
              text: firstNodeText,
              state: { expanded: true },
              children: state.childrens,
            });
          } else {
            res = [
              {
                text: firstNodeText,
                state: { expanded: true },
                children: [{ text: noDataFound }],
              },
            ];
          }
          commit(m.SET_DOCUMENT_FLOW_TREE, res);
        });
      });
    },
    [a.UPDATE_DOCUMENT_ID]({ commit }, payload) {
      commit(m.SET_DOCUMENT_ID, payload);
    },
    [a.ADD_CHILDREN_TO_NODE]({commit},payload) {
      let doc = payload.doc;
      let childrens = [];
      let matRegNodeText = "";
        let i = 0;
        
          Object.keys(doc).forEach((key) =>{
            let docId = doc[key][0].docNum;
            let deliveryParams = new ParamsBuilder(url)
              .param(ParamsBuilder.UrlReplacements.NUM, docId)
              .build();
  
              Http.get({
                params: deliveryParams,
              }).then((deliveryResponse) => {
                if (deliveryResponse.result) {
                  matRegNodeText =
                    (doc[key][0].docType.category === "DELIVERY" ? goodsIssue : null) +
                    "\t\t\t" +
                    deliveryResponse.result.goodsReceiptNum +
                    "\t\t\t" +
                    deliveryResponse.result.actualMovDate;
                }
                  let child = {
                    text: Strings.fsa.cdp.df.position + "\t" + response.result[i].docPos.posNum,
                    state: { expanded: true },
                    children: [{ text: matRegNodeText }],
                  };
                  childrens.push(child);
                  i++;
              });
        });
      commit(m.SET_CHILDRENS,childrens);
    }
  },
};

export default documentFlow;
```

My question: is it possible to call an action from an action on the same module?
My problem is that before I didn't use the action to build the node (in the action loop my object doc to retrieve the data) but before being able to push the array childrens into property children of the object res, it was called asynchronous the commit, I thought about putting that piece of code inside a promise and then building the tree node but the result was the same.